# svn commit after merge with different mergeinfo

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn

I have a problem (more a question) with tortoise svn.
I have created a branch from my trunk. because the Path was not right in subversion, I didn't "Move" the branch, rather I deleted it (also in subversion) and created a new one (in the right path).

Now I am able to merge my branch into my trunk without any Conflicts, but while committing my merged trunk, I get a message with:

> "Non-revursive commit of moved/renamed folders."

I managed to find out what's causing this and it seems like it is the mergeinfo.
When I compare the mergeinfo I see the first branch I created (which was wrong and has been deleted).

So I don't know if

- a) I can proceed with the commit as I don't know the effects of
  having a non-correct mergeinfo.
- b) how to remove the false information in the mergeinfo.

Does anyone has a solution for me?